# How to keep label active when input field inside the label is active?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the label like `<label>name:<input></label>`
and the css like 
`label:active{/*properties*/}`
I'd like the properties to be applied to `name` inside `<label>` when I click on `<input>` it gets applied but it looses focus to the `<input>` soon after I click it.

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GuCk4/2/

Comment: @anglimass the code is in the first two lines of my post. instead of the /*properties*/ I have a font-weight:bold; that's all it is to it.

Comment: By the way, the focus pseudo-class is `:focus` not `:active`.

Comment: @boltclock check this http://jsfiddle.net/GuCk4/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If I understand your question, you could just do this... without changing any HTML.</strike>

```
label, input, input:focus{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/GuCk4/4/

BTW: you don't really need `input:focus` here... at least in my tests on Chrome.  You may need it for other browsers.

**EDIT**

Okay, after @Mohsen's comment, I reread the question.

What you want is a parent selector in css.  This does not exist.  Since css relies on the cascade, it applies styles down the DOM not up it.

So, the only way to do what you want is to rewrite your HTML, as per @Mohsen's answer, or use some jQuery, like so

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('font-weight','bold');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('font-weight','normal');
});
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/GuCk4/5/

Comment: He want style the label when the input get focus. It's not what he want I think

Comment: You'r using JavaScript. It's not fair

Comment: You're right @Mohsen that this is not css only.  But as I mentioned in my answer, there is no way to do this with css WITHOUT changing the HTML.  If the OP wants the same HTML, he needs to use js.  Otherwise, I said he could do what you said and rewrite the HTML.  BTW: I did NOT downvote you.  That was someone else.

Answer (score 0):

label{display:block}
label:active,label:hover,label:focus{font-weight:700}

works how you want it to.

@steveax is correct, don't put the label after the input unless it's a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using jQuery 1.7+, here's a nicer bit of jQuery to toggle an "active" `class` on a `label` wrapped around an `<input type="checkbox">`.

```
$("body").on(
  "click",
  "label input[type=checkbox]",
  function(){
    $(this).parent("label").toggleClass("active");
  }
);
```

**Demo:** [http://jsbin.com/iHaJeCe/3](http://jsbin.com/iHaJeCe/3/edit#javascript,output)